# Install libtools on mac

Tags: macos

I wanted to installs libtools on mac. I went to the apple developer site and downloaded the .dgm that downloaded the cmdline tools for Xcode for Mountain Lion.

But when I go to terminal and type libtools it says that the bash command is not found.

Could someone please tell me how to install libtools on mac.

Comment: Did you actually run the installer in the DMG?

Comment: Yes Matt, I did run the installer. It said installation is complete. I restarted to ensure the changes/installations are picked up.

But still libtools on **Terminal** returns command not found.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12104236/7758804) by the question OP, the question should be closed as caused by a typo, as the op was using `libtools`, not the correct `libtool`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you installed brew like this

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

You can just write in terminal

```
brew install libtool
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that `libtool` is called `glibtool` on OSX:

> This tool is installed in OS X as glibtool to avoid a name conflict with NeXT libtool.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002850-SW5

Answer (score 3):

Install *libtool* on MacOS as below -

```
brew install libtool
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
brew uninstall libtool
```

```bash
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool /usr/local/opt/libtool/libexec/gnubin/libtool
```

Answer (score -1):

Extreme rookie mistake. The command is libtool and not libtools.
I found the installation link in **Apple Developers website**
You've to un-pack the package and it will automatically start the installation on Xcode.

Comment: can you please provide the link here?